# Error: Big Query REGEX_EXTRACT Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

## My attempt to extract the #2 from #1 in BigQuery

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(",\"AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki\"", r"(?<=,\")[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

**#1 String from which I am trying to extract**

```
,"AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki"
```

**#2 Expected result of the REGEX_EXTRACT**

```
AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki
```

Can someone please help me in the Regex to correctly escape quotes and brackets to extract #2 from #1?

Comment: Do you have a comma separated list of values?  If so, please include that in your question, highlight which component you want to match, and then give us logic for how to fish out that component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the error has to do with your lookbehind, which `REGEX_EXTRACT` does not support.  One workaround might be to use `REGEX_REPLACE` with a capture group:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r",\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"", "\\1")
```

Here I assume `col` would have a value like:

```
,"AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki"
```

which you mentioned in your question.

Comment: With this, I am getting AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki"

Comment: ... which matches your stated expected result.  Do you expect something different?

Comment: I expect AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki 
no quotes at end

Comment: @PreeteshGaitonde `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r",\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"", "\\1")` ... can you try this?  I think the issue is that I left a trailing quote off the end of the pattern I used to match.

Comment: God damn I love stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ",\"AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki\"" string1
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(string1, r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)') string2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row string2  
1   AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki
```

or just simply

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(",\"AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki\"", r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)')
```

Btw, note: BigQuery provides regular expression support using the [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) library - where `(?<=re)` is not supported. Meantime, from your example it is not clear why you would need it as above examples do the work without it

Meantime, if you are looking for regexp that is the closest to yours (in question) - you can use `r'(?:,\")([a-zA-Z0-9]*)'` as in below example

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(",\"AQk8tmAg94ZUZwqYKd6kHrswiVZR0wKNuTvSpr6COCLpki\"", r'(?:,\")([a-zA-Z0-9]*)')
```