# BQSQLException: Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: see full error in post as title cannot contain certain characters)

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Please find dummy data and my attempted solution at the end of this post.

I started learning REGEX in the last several days and am creating a REGEX to exclude any private IP addresses from my dataset. My dataset has a column `url`, which shows from which IP address a company performed an action. This column contains all kinds of IP addresses in the `url` format.

I have created a query that should output only non-local IP addresses (which are a part of URL. The query I have is as follows:

```
WITH table_1 AS(

SELECT 'http://localhost:9999' AS url UNION ALL
SELECT 'https://localhost:0000' AS url UNION ALL
SELECT 'http://stackoverflow.com/challenge' AS url UNION ALL
SELECT 'https://arseniyaskingquestion.ru/SO' AS url 

)

SELECT url
FROM table_1
WHERE url NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT url
                  FROM table_1
                  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, r'((http(s)?):\/\/)(((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$|(.*\.local)|(.*local\.)|(.*localhost)|(.*\.internal)|(.*csb.)|(.*codesandbox)|(.*lvh\.me)|(.*.ngrok.)|(.*nip\.io)|(.*.test)).*'))
ORDER BY url DESC
```

When I run this query, I get the following error message: `BQSQLException: Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?!`

I searched StackOverflow and noticed that 1 solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098074/error-big-query-regex-extract-cannot-parse-regular-expression-invalid-perl-ope), but I could not implement it successfully using `REGEXP_REPLACE` - I kept getting other errors as I tried to implement this and after reading Google Big Query documentation.

As you can see from my code snippet, I am trying to output only non-local IP addresses (which are a part of a full url link). Therefore, the expected output is:

```
                url
----------------------------------
http://stackoverflow.com/challenge
https://arseniyaskingquestion.ru/SO
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `LIKE` clause not suitable?

```
WHERE LOWER(url) NOT LIKE '%localhost%'
```

---

The primary issue with your regex is the use of the negative lookahead `(?!$)`.

Google BigQuery uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2) and it omits support for lookarounds.

At regex101 you should develop your regexes using the Golang option since that is re2-based. See https://regex101.com/r/HAV5J1/1/ and it will explain why your regex is failing.

---

Additionally your subquery seems wildly inefficient:

```
WHERE url NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT url
                  FROM table_1
                  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, r'((http(s)?):\/\/)(((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$|(.*\.local)|(.*local\.)|(.*localhost)|(.*\.internal)|(.*csb.)|(.*codesandbox)|(.*lvh\.me)|(.*.ngrok.)|(.*nip\.io)|(.*.test)).*'))
```

Could it not be condensed to:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, r'MY_REGEX')
```

or:

```
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, r'MY_REGEX') = false
```

I have no experience with BigQuery.

Comment: Localhost is not the only thing I am removing. As you can see in my REGEX, many things are to be excluded. I could use many LIKE statements, but I am purposefully trying to execute this query with REGEX for the purpose of learning. Therefore, looking for a REGEX-related solution.

Comment: @Arsik36 You need to provide a larger dataset of things which should and should not match. I am confused as to why `(?!$)` is needed. Your regex isn't exactly easy-to-read...

Comment: @Arsik36 In regards to the commendable regex which you've built I would say you should definitely play around more on regex101 because hands-on with immediate feedback is the best way to learn regex. If you want to avoid future issues then brush up on supported syntax via their [documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex contains a lookahead and RE2 does not support lookaheads.

If you are satisfied with your pattern all in all, and you just need to fix that lookahead issue, you can unwrap the IP matching part and use

```js
https?:\/\/((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){4}$|.*\.local|.*local\.|.*localhost|.*\.internal|.*csb.|.*codesandbox|.*lvh\.me|.*.ngrok.|.*nip\.io|.*.test).*
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZDdvT/1/).

See [this IP matching regex page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) for details.